# How to read HTTP2 HPACK compressed headers using tshark

Tags: http2, pcap, tshark

I have a Pcap file which has around 2000 packets.
Some of these packets have HTTP2 headers in them that seem to be compressed using HPACK.

When opening them in wireshark I am able to see the actual values of these headers, however when loading it in using tshark I am only shown the raw compressed bytes.

From my understanding the compressed headers will only be able to be de-compressed if the table used for the HPACK is able to be created.

Seeing as I am able to see the compressed headers inside of wire shark, I would assume that the table is being created just fine in wireshark in order to be visable from the packets in the pcap.

So how do I get tshark to de-compress these headers?

I saw this example: https://quantonganh.com/2020/05/05/grpc-http2-headers
But that didn't seem to work and only showed me the compressed bytes.

Comment: Did you try running `tshark` with the `-2` option for 2-pass analysis?